# Expected value and Lindeberg condition

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Lindeberg condition (classic) states that for a random variable $X$ with finite mean and variance, $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, and for every $\varepsilon>0$
$$E(X^2 \boldsymbol{I}_{\{ X>\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\sigma\}}) \rightarrow 0, \quad \mbox{as} \quad n\rightarrow \infty,$$ where $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the indicator function.

Now I'd like to prove this. Let's say $X$ is a continuous random variable with distribution $P_X$, then
$$E(X^2 \boldsymbol{I}_{\{ X>\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\sigma\}}) = \int_{X>\varepsilon \sqrt{n}\sigma}x^2 dP_X$$ I think I get the intuition of this integral: for a fixed $\varepsilon$ when $n$ gets larger, the set $X>\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\sigma$ gets smaller. So I'm integrating on a set that "tends" to the empty set.

I thought the proof may be something like
$$\sigma^2 + \mu^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2 dP_X = \int_{X\leq\varepsilon \sqrt{n}\sigma}x^2 dP_X + \int_{X>\varepsilon \sqrt{n}\sigma}x^2 dP_X,$$ but I'm not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since the mean and variance are finite, then
$$
\sigma^2 + (EX)^2 = EX^2 = M < \infty
$$

Now, you know that $EX^2 = \int x^2 dP_x$, so as you did, you break down the integral
$$
EX^2= \int_{X\leq \epsilon \sqrt n \sigma} x^2 dP_x +
\int_{X>\epsilon \sqrt n \sigma} x^2 dP_x
$$

Then, taking the limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty } EX^2 =
 \int_{X\leq \infty} x^2 dP_x +\lim_{n\to \infty}
\int_{X>\epsilon \sqrt n \sigma} x^2 dP_x =
M +
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\int_{X>\epsilon \sqrt n \sigma} x^2 dP_x
$$

Which proves what you wanted to show.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you establish that the integral over $X \leq \infty$ is M? I see the conclusion, since $EX^2$ does not depend on $n$, the limit should be $M$, so my intregal should be $0$

Comment: Oh, wait, the integral over $X \leq \infty$ is the integral over $\mathbb{R}$, so that integral is the very definition of $EX^2$. Right?

Comment: Yeah, that’s it